# call a controller and method on select change with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

i want to call a AJAX query on select change.
I found this code fragment, but it doesnt work on rails 4, or im doing it wrong

```
<%= f.select(:resource_id, Resource.all.collect {|resource| [ resource.name, resource.id ] }, :class => "medium", :onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'})) %>
```

and im geting this error

```
undefined method `remote_function' for #<#<Class:0x007f3daff24a88>:0x007f3d9c670210>
```

any ideas what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a hint:

```
<%= f.select(:resource_id, Resource.all.collect {|resource| [ resource.name, resource.id ] }, :class => "medium" %>

#javascript code to make an Ajax call:
$('select#your_model_name_resource_id').on('change', function(event) {
  var selected_resource_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax('/relative/path/to/your/action', data: { id: selected_resource_id })
})
```

When a user change the value of the select, it should perform an Ajax request to your server at this location: `/relative/path/to/your/action?id=12` (if id selected was twelve)

Comment: when i run this script, i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ". what can be wrong ?

Comment: Don't copy-paste the comment above the javascript ("#javascript code to make an Ajax call" -> don't copy it)

Answer (score 2):

The `remote_function` has been deprecated and removed from rails. You need to write some javascript now (very simple though).

Unless you are willing to install prototype-rails gem, which will add this helper back to your rails.